# Use of unresolved identifier 'PhoneAuthProvider'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make window to verify user phone number with firebase , unfortunately I have serious issue the class PhoneAuthProvider cannot be found in firebase library! But in their [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) they mention its exists there

**POD :**

```
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'AMTooltip'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

Here the viewcontroller

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

    //.....

            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+96170023344") { (verificationID, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
                // ...
            }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does it show an error at import statement - 'import Firebase'?

Comment: add you podfile in question.

Comment: done , added my pod file , and yes i am importing Firebase and firebaseauth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution this may help someone else ,

i need to set the version for firebase 4.0+ , the weird is i already updated the pod the the repo but i don't know why its not taken the 4+ version , anyway below is my new POD

```
  pod 'Firebase', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'AMTooltip'
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

Comment: Hi @jack, I have a follow-up question to this. 

I am also using Google Analytics which requires a `Firebase/Core` version that's lower than the one you've provided. Is there a way to have separate dependencies for different pods?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to set the version number you want , then `pod update` , and yes you can have separate dep from different pods just set the version number

Answer (score 5):

Here is reference,

How to add Firebase in iOS : [Add Firebase to your iOS Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

I suggest you to first try with this sample code available in github: [github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) and check does it work in your system.

> Note: 
>   
> - Ensure, `FIRPhoneAuthProvider.h` exist in your pod source or not.
>   FIRPhoneAuthProvider.h is `PhoneAuthProvider` in swift.
>   
> - Also ensure, you've installed all required pods.
>   
> - Update all Firebase pods (or remove all and install again)

It's working properly in my system with above code.
Here is snapshot with `FIRPhoneAuthProvider.h` and podfile

[image]

Please go through each steps, and identify, which you've not followed. It should solve your problem.

**Integrate Using CocoaPods**

Create a Podfile if you don't have one:

```
$ cd your-project directory
$ pod init
```

Add the pods that you want to install. You can include a Pod in your Podfile like this:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Install the pods and open the .xcworkspace file to see the project in Xcode.

```
$ pod install
$ open your-project.xcworkspace
```

Download a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and include it in your app.

**Integrate without CocoaPods**

If you don't want to use Cocoapods you can still take advantage of the Firebase SDKs by importing the frameworks directly.

- Download the [framework SDK zip](https://firebase.google.com/download/ios) (this is a ~100MB file and may take some time).
- Unzip and see the README file for which Frameworks to include in to your project.
- Add the [ObjC linker flag](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html) in your Other Linker Settings in your target's build settings

-

**Initialize Firebase in your app**

Import the Firebase module in your UIApplicationDelegate subclass:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
```

Configure a FIRApp shared instance, typically in your application's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:`

```
// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
FirebaseApp.configure()


PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) { (verificationID, error) in
  if let error = error {
    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
  // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i did all above , same issue my project can't see `PhoneAuthProvider` class

Comment: I suggest you to first try with this sample code available in github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk   and check does it work in your system.

Comment: i m getting error on "    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)"

Value of type 'CreateAccountVC' has no member 'showMessagePrompt' .

how to resolve that do i need to show alert and pass title error.localizedDescription

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of Firebase your pos installed? It needs to be 4.
 you can run

`pod update`